# Is override base method in Odoo is good option?

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo

I created a new method in my custom module and I want to use my method when user clicks button `confirm` in sale order. so I did research and found easy solution to complete this job.

- Override base method. In this case is method `action_confirm()` in `sale.py` by use `super()` method.

so I am just wondering, is it the right way?Is there a better solution than this? please suggest me.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: @KlausD. yes it work fine. i just wonder it have other best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to overwrite any method is to use `super()`, to execute the old functionality and avoid destroying the functionality of other module methods which also overwrite that source method. If you do that you're doing well. But sometimes you'll find situations in which you can't use `super()` and you need to copy the source code to modify anything inside. In those cases, you must be careful and be aware of what you're overwriting.

> Example A

- You've the base method `action_confirm()`, which is created by `sale` module.
- You install a module named `sale_extension`, which overwrites `action_confirm()` method using `super()`.
- Then you install your custom module, where you're also overwriting `action_confirm()` with `super()`.
- When `action_confirm()` is called, it's going to execute `sale`, `sale_extension` and your module functionality.

> Example B

- You've the base method `action_confirm()`, which is created by `sale` module.
- You install a module named `sale_extension`, which overwrites `action_confirm()` method using `super()`.
- Then you install your custom module, where you're also overwriting `action_confirm()` without `super()`, so you've been copied the source code of `action_confirm()` and modified it.
- When `action_confirm()` is called, it's going to execute `sale` and your module functionality, but not the `sale_extension` one.
- So you should have understood first and then have added the code introduced by `sale_extension` in the source code you had copied, and then, modify it.
- The problem with this case is the future modules you can install, if they overwrite `action_confirm()`, your code is going to ignore their changes.

So the conclusion is that if you use `super()`, you're not bound to have problems in your method when installing new modules (although there are cases in which even with `super()`, you'll have to modify your code to adapt it to the new installed module functionality).

Answer (score 2):

Overiding is used when :

- Extending a basic functionnality, by redefining the method, calling
  the motherclass method by using super
- Replacing the original functionnality when a new behavior is needed

Yes you can overide the method by inheriting the class "sale.order" like this :

```
class SalesOrderExtend(models.Model):
 _inherit = "sale.order"
 @api.multi
 def action_confirm(self):
  ret = super(SalesOrderExtend,self).action_confirm()
  ....
  your code 
  ....
  return True
```

)

Check some examples of overiding superclass method in this payroll internationalization code fromp odoo :

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/l10n_in_hr_payroll/models/l10n_in_hr_payroll.py